# jquery addclass and radio button handling

Tags: jquery

I'm having some trouble.  I'm trying to add a class according to what value the option selected has.

I thought this would work.

```
  if ($("input#field_24").val() == "patient") {
  $("div[id*='-form'] input#field_25").addClass(" required");
  }
```

### EDIT

[Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/C7Gg3/1/)

Sorry to have added a similar question.  This answered mine.

Thanks!

Comment: a radio button's value is static, only it's 'checked' attribute changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using selected options, you're not dealing with an input field, it'd be `select#field_24`.

If you're using radios: `$input#field_24:checked`.

If you need the `VALUE` of the selected option in a select field: `select#field_24:selected`